# Can I set a font family for italic font style and another font family for other font styles in VSCode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, fonts

I want to use "Operator Mono" font only for **italic font style** and for other font styles: "bold, regular, semibold..." I want to use "Fira Code" font. Can I implement this in VSCode?

I had tried to change the font family to:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Operator Mono Light Italic', 'Fira Code', Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace"
```

But it not worked, the editor only show 'Fira Code' font family.

Comment: If you can identify what tm grammar scopes are using italic, then I think it would be pretty easy. Review the docs on how to navigate this and see if it gets you closer https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-tokens-and-scopes

Comment: I use a theme extension and I don't know what grammar scopes are using italic in this theme ...

Comment: This is doable, you’ll just have to find what your theme uses italics for and override those tokens. No one can really answer that for you. That link above talks about something called the [scope inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) which will tell you the name of the scope. Once you have it you can just add it to your settings [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108220/2353523) I only linked mine because I can find it quick, although there are way more thorough examples out there covering it.

Comment: Thank you, I think I complete 99%. I found what's scope the theme use italics, and I update my setting file, but in the end, I can't change `fontFamily` attribute in `settings` object because VSCode did not allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find a solution: [vscode-custom-css](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css), you can write CSS code for custom your editor most.

Thanks for [soulshined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2353523/soulshined), I can't find the final solution without your tips.

This is my final result: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/douknow/eae657279d43cd71504c021facb15e34)