# I want to edit a vscode theme, so it could support different font-families for different tokens

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, themes, token

I want do edit a vscode theme, so it could support different font-families for different tokens. But the types or the scheme tells that it's not supported. So I wonder where are those files that it is referencing to, I'd like to edit them and to make themes support different font-families for different tokens

Comment: "_So I wonder where are those files that it is referencing to_" what files _who_ is referencing to? You want to edit VS Code itself and run a custom build of VS Code? Or PR a change upstream? as it is, I can't tell if this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77329258/11107541, but it seems like it could be.